# Adding Filter option in Excel Files using Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am working on the creation of excel files using Pandas Pivot Tables.
My table headers currently look like this: [image: Current]

And, I want to add filter option in the column headers as shown in this picture. [image]

Can you please help me with it?

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

I don’t think pandas can do that, it’s just saving data in excel format, for which it uses backend libraries such as [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

This library seems to have an `AutoFilter` class with an [`add_filter_column()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.filters.html?highlight=filter#openpyxl.worksheet.filters.AutoFilter.add_filter_column) function, in the `openpyxl.worksheet.filters` module:

> Add row filter for specified column.
> Parameters:
>
> - col_id (int) – Zero-origin column id. 0 means first column.
> - vals (str[]) – Value list to show.
> - blank (bool) – Show rows that have blank cell if True (default=`False`)

There is a complete example, with code, in the [*Using filters and sort*](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#using-filters-and-sorts) documentation.

Note the important caveat at the bottom of that page:

> This will add the relevant instructions to the file but will **neither actually filter nor sort**.

Comment: Thank You! This part of documentation is gonna help a lot.